# How to fix JRELoadError on macOS 10.15.4 Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina, java

When I download or brew-cask-install JOSM, jEdit (and propably any other java app) and run it, I get **JRELoadError**.

I have:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "14" 2020-03-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14+36-1461)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14+36-1461, mixed mode, sharing)
```

How to fix that error?

Comment: Do you also get this error with JDK 13 ?? - I can't start up my eclipse with JDK 14, but with JDK 13 I can - and it is also some JRE load error (can't remember the exact text).

Comment: Yes, I do get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by installing Java 8u241 from java.com instead of Homebrew.